# Exporting functional Plotly sunburst plot

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, hierarchical-data, sunburst-diagram

Does anyone know how I can export a plotly sunburst plot as a standalone file which can keep all the functionalities, like annotation while hovering and expansion by click?

- Visualizing a hierarchical data with plotly.sunburst in python is a beautiful and beneficial way of presenting it in the best order, while you are able to hover the values to see the annotation, click on each parent section to collapse and expand the child values, etc.. But to present the visualized data (plot) independently without having to open the Python notebook, needs the plot to be saved and exported in a standalone file format that allows keeping every functionality available.
  Does anyone know how to do this? and what file format can give this luxury to us?
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Saving to an HTML file will do the trick:
[doc](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).